# Thread main with 2 sons thread to loop x times product & consumer

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I've wrote a program in which the thread main creates 2 sons threads . One waits a random time then produces a random value between 1 and 6 and puts the value into the randomValue variable . The other waits and reads the global variable randomValue and prints the variable.So I used a single semaphore to be sure that the thread who reads will always read the value written by the other thread.

I want to modify so that each thread does I don't know x loops( 2,3...) so that it can produce x times a random value and put this value into randomValue and the other thread will read the x times the randomValue variable and will print it . Any idea to modify the code is welcomed . Thank you very much .

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

/* variable shared by producer and consumer 
 (producer writes a value between 1 and 6) */

long randomValue = 0;
/**semaphore  **/
sem_t mex;


// function that create a random sleep-time (to induce unpredictability)
static int duration(int min, int max)
{
  static int first_time = 1;

  // Seed the random number generator with the current time
  // of day if we haven't done so yet.
  if (first_time) {
    first_time = 0;
    srand48((int) time(NULL));
  }
  return (int) (min + drand48()*(max - min));
}

/* producer program */
void *producer(void *arg) {
  char statearray[256];

  // Initialize random generator
  // Note that initstate and random are not threadsafe
  initstate(time(NULL), statearray, 256);

   sleep(duration(1,3));
   printf("prod: producing ...\n");
//random value 1 et 6
   randomValue = random();
   randomValue = ((double) randomValue / RAND_MAX)*6+1;
//put the value
   printf("prod: delivering  %ld\n", randomValue);
   sem_post(&mex); 
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/* consumer program */
void *consumer(void *arg) {


  sleep(duration(1,5));
  sem_wait(&mex);
  printf("cons: consuming ...\n");
  // 

  printf("cons: received %ld\n", randomValue);


  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/* main thread */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  pthread_t tidprod, tidcons;


    if (sem_init(&mex,0,0)  != 0){
    perror("sem_init");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

  if (pthread_create(&tidprod, NULL, producer, NULL) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create");
  }
  if (pthread_create(&tidcons, NULL, consumer, NULL) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create");
  }


  if (pthread_join(tidcons, NULL) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_join prod");
  }

  if (pthread_join(tidprod, NULL) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_join prod");
  }

  fflush(stdout);
  pthread_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with a few modifications:

- Instead of one semaphore, use two: one semaphore to tell consumer that a 
  number is ready, one to tell the producer that consumer is ready to consume.
- Have a special value to indicate to the consumer that the producer won't 
  produce anymore.

So, you can change your code this way:

*Semaphores declaration*

```
/*semaphores  */
/* Set by producer when production is ready */
sem_t mex_prod;
/* Set by consumer when ready to consume */
sem_t mex_cons;
```

*Semaphores init*

```
/* by default, nothing produced */
if (sem_init(&mex_prod,0,0)  != 0){
    perror("sem_init");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
/* by default, consumer is not ready */
if (sem_init(&mex_cons,0,0)  != 0){
    perror("sem_init");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

*producer thread function*

(I removed your comment)

```
void *producer(void *arg) {
    char statearray[256];
    initstate(time(NULL), statearray, 256);

    /* choose how much to product  */
    int number_of_productions = 2 + random()%5;

    printf("prod: %d to produce\n", number_of_productions );

    /* this loop can be replaced by some for (i = 0; i< num; ++i) loop */
    while(number_of_productions--)
    {
        sleep(duration(1,3));           

        /* wait for consumer to be ready */
        sem_wait(&mex_cons);

        printf("prod: producing ...\n");

        randomValue = random();
        randomValue = ((double) randomValue / RAND_MAX)*6+1;

        printf("prod: delivering  %ld\n", randomValue);
        sem_post(&mex_prod); 
    }

    sem_wait(&mex_cons);

    /* generate a special value to tell the consumer that no new value
       will be given */
    randomValue  = -1;

    sem_post(&mex_prod); 

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

*consumer thread function*

```
void *consumer(void *arg) {

    /* tell producer that consumer is ready */
    sem_post(&mex_cons);

    /* since we don't know how many value will be generated, we have an
       infinite loop */
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(duration(1,5));
        sem_wait(&mex_prod);
        printf("cons: consuming ...\n");

        printf("cons: received %ld\n", randomValue);

        /* value has been consumed, tell producer we are ready for a new one */
        sem_post(&mex_cons); 

        /* if randomValue is -1, we break the loop since no more value will come */
        if (-1 == randomValue)             
            break;

    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear if you only want to send and receive multiple values.

For sending and receiving multiple values, use for loop in producer and consumer and an array as randomValue. If you want to produce one value and consume it first, the loop will include "sem_post(&mex);" in producer and "sem_wait(&mex);" in the loop. Otherwise, sem_post() and sem_wait() will be outside loop.